# Error in a php echo in onchange function parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('ord_id',$pacc_ord, $value['pac_cod'], 'id="IdPac" onchange="func1(this),func2(this, echo $value['prod_id'];);"')?>
```

i need to print the value of `$value['prod_id']` (number) 
in my function arguments. but it doesn't work

how can i solve that?

Comment: <?php echo form_dropdown('ord_id', $pacc_ord, $value['pac_cod'], 'id="IdPac" onchange="func1(this),func2(this, '.$value['prod_id'].'"'); ?>

Comment: form_dropdown is supposed to be a php function or javascript?

Comment: form_dropdown is php function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?php echo form_dropdown('ord_id',$pacc_ord, $value['pac_cod'], 'id="IdPac" onchange="func1(this),func2(this, '.$value['prod_id'].');"')?>`

You don't have to use echo when passing the values as parameters. Just concatenate (using '..') the `prod_id` into the last parameter.